# If $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ is a convergent series of positive real numbers, then so is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n^{n/({n+1})}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, contest-math

This is the $1988$ Putnam $B4$ Problem:

> Prove that if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ is a convergent series of positive real numbers, then so is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n^{n/({n+1})}$.

My problem lies in figuring out what to do in the case that $0\lt a_n \lt 1$ for all $n$. I imagine that it must have something to do with the limit comparison test. Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Note: You can find many Putnam answers, including this one, [here](http://www.math.niu.edu/~rusin/problems-math/).

Comment: Erm . . If each $a_n \ge 1$, then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ diverges. . .

Comment: Yeah, your "trivial case" is not a case at all.

Comment: @Strants Thanks, I removed the misleading statement about the "trivial" case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Limit comparison seems good. What can we say about $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{a_n^{n/(n+1)}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n^{1/(n+1)}?$$

Comment: Does the right hand side go to zero since $a_n$ converges?

Comment: You don't want it to go to zero, really you just want it to have a finite $\limsup$ - that is $\limsup a_n^{1/(n+1)}<+\infty$.

Comment: Not zero, but can you argue it's got a finite limit (or even lim sup)?

Comment: Sorry for reviving, but I don't see how the application works here - shouldn't our limits be the opposite way round? According to the following post:

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1761541/proof-of-the-strenghtened-limit-comparison-test/1761562

Answer (score 8):

Let $A=\{n: a_n \le2^{-n-1}\}$ and $B=\{n:a_n>2^{-n-1}\}$.

If $n\in A$, then 
$a^{n/(n+1)}_n\le 2^{-n}$ and hence
$$
\sum_{n\in A}a^{n/(n+1)}_n\le \sum_{n\in A}2^{-n}\le 1.
$$

If $n\in B$, then $a_n> 2^{-n-1}$, then $2^{n+1}a_n> 1$, and thus $2a_n^{1/(n+1)}>1$
and therefore $2a_n>a_n^{n/(n+1)}$. Hence
$$
\sum_{n\in B}a_n^{n/(n+1)}\le 2\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}a_n.
$$
Thus 
$$
\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}a_n^{n/(n+1)}=
\sum_{n\in A}a_n^{n/(n+1)}+\sum_{n\in B}a_n^{n/(n+1)}
\le 1+2\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}a_n.
$$